# How to pass an in memory collection to a generic repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

I've created a very rough working example using the repository pattern which receives an in memory collection.  The use case is simply to supply working test data while I develop the rest of the application.  The repository will be updated to work with EF later.

I'm unclear how I can pass an instance of the PersonRepo object containing a list of people during the application startup in a .NET Core web api project.

I have something similar to this in the application startup:

```
 services.AddScoped<IRepository<IPersonDto>, Repository<PersonDto>();
```

The unit test proves that the below example work.  I just need to know how to get the DI stuff to accept an instantiated object containing my collection.

```
  public class PersonDto
{
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class SetupRepo{

    public List<PersonDto> PersonRepo = new List<PersonDto>(){
        new PersonDto{
            PersonId = 1,
            Age = 24,
            Name = "Person 1"
        },
        new PersonDto{
            PersonId = 2,
            Age = 34,
            Name = "Person 2"
        }
    };
}

public class Repository<T> 
{
    private ICollection<PersonDto> _tempRepo;
    public Repository(ICollection<PersonDto> tempRepo)
    {
        _tempRepo = tempRepo;
    }

    public PersonDto GetById(int id)
    {
        var result = _tempRepo.Where(x => x.PersonId == id);
        return result.FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```

Unit test

```
 [Test]
    public void TestRepository()
    {
        var testRepo = new SetupRepo();
        var testObject = new Repository<PersonDto>(testRepo.PersonRepo);
        var result = testObject.GetById(1);
        Assert.That(result != null);
    }
```

Comment: FWIW, if you intend to go with EF, use EF. EF Core has an in-memory DB provider that works great for testing. If you intend to use *any* ORM, you should *not* implement the repository pattern. Instead, if abstraction is your goal consider the service layer or CQRS patterns.

Comment: @ChrisPratt is right, EF already implements repository pattern and unit of work pattern so creating your own generic repositories with EF is redundant.  You'll end up with a heap of pointless wrapper classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the overloads on the `AddScoped` method, this allows you to define a function to be called each time the IRepository is instantiated.

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository<IPersonDto>>((services) => {
   var testRepo = new SetupRepo();
   var personRepository= new Repository<PersonDto>(testRepo.PersonRepo);
   return personRepository;
});
```